# double quote input is breaking the json structure how to fix that

Tags: php, json, concatenation

I'm trying to take input from the user 
when I'm giving an input like "kaushik" the json output is not coming

this is my code

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['name'])){
    $name = strip_tags(@$_POST['name']);
    //echo $name;
    $json = '{
                "a":"'.$name.'",
                "b":"Kishore",
                "c":"ramesh",
                "d":"Suresh",
                "e":"ramu"
            }';
    $jsonOutput = json_decode($json,true);
    print_r($jsonOutput);
}
?>
<form name = "myform" action = "" method = "POST">
    Name <input type = "name" name = "name"/></br>
    <input type= "Submit" name = "submit" value = "show"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Why not do it properly and let `json_encode()` handle the escaping? Also, are you sure the method is ever entered at all?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I've to take the input from the user. How can i do that ?

Comment: I've tested your script and it's output is right.

Comment: I'm using json_encode now . Thnaks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the double-quotes first.  i.e. `\"` in place of `"`

```
$name = addslashes($name);
```

However, generally you don't want to generate JSON yourself. You'd be better off creating an array and letting `json_encode()` do the work.

Comment: kaushik 'kishore' failing on this condition or in case of single quotes condition.

Comment: Single quotes are a better solution than this.

Comment: The issue with doing addslashes is the fact that you may get cases where you don't need something being escaped that will be, then you get issues doing correct unescaping of values, once you've run addslashes.